# Django S3 [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto

I'm trying to upload files from my django app to Amazon S3 service. It works well with small files (under 300ko) but with other files (300ko +) I have a "[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer" error. I tried with django 1.4 and 1.3, python2.7 and 2.6 but without success. It's really weird. four days now i'm looking for a solution.
thnx in advance.

**EDIT**
Found out what was the problem. I'm using guincorn as my django server which close the request after 30sec by default. So I had to increase the timout to get it work and make async request.
web: python manage.py run_gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 3 --timeout 900 -k gevent

Answer (score 0):

I use **s3cmd** to publish content from my Django app to amazon-s3

```
subprocess.call(["s3cmd", "put", "-P", "-r", "-c", s3conf_path, "--exclude=.xml", src,  fileserver_path + '/data/'])
```

and i am able to publish content that are more 150 mb